# How to echo 0, When not check checkbox?

Tags: php

How to echo 0, When not check checkbox ?

When press submit button, It's will echo 11
But i want to echo 101 (echo 0 for not checked ckeckbox).

How can i do that ?

```
<form id="form02" name="form02" method="post">
    <input name="h_type[]" type="checkbox" id="h_type[]" value="0" checked/><input  type="hidden" name="more[]" value="1"> <br/>
    <input name="h_type[]" type="checkbox" id="h_type[]" value="1" /><input  type="hidden" name="more[]" value="1"> <br/>
    <input name="h_type[]" type="checkbox" id="h_type[]" value="2" checked/><input  type="hidden" name="more[]" value="1"> <br/>    
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>


<?php
$data_h_type=$_POST['h_type'];
$data_more=$_POST['more'];

if(count($data_h_type)>0){
    foreach($data_h_type as $key=>$value){
          echo $data_more[$value];
                  echo "<br>";
    }   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo isset($data_more[$value]) ? $data_more[$value] : 0;
```